# ng-table header select all check box

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ng-table for display data. i am using below code to do select all checkboxe. that select all check box insert using text/ng-template. if i use select all checkbox outside the ng-table, all functions work. but inside the ng-table with text/ng-template , functions not working.

```js
  $scope.selectAll = function() {
        angular.forEach($scope.invoiceApprovalList, function(invoiceApproval) {
         invoiceApproval.checkboxItem= $scope.selectedAll;
        });
      };

      // use the array "every" function to test if ALL items are checked
      $scope.checkIfAllSelected = function() {
        $scope.selectedAll = $scope.invoiceApprovalList.every(function(invoiceApproval) {
          return invoiceApproval.checkboxItem == true;
        })
      };
```

```html
<script type="text/ng-template" id="all.html">
 <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="selectAll()" /> 
</script>
<table ng-table="invoicetableParams" ng-show="invoicetableParams!=null"  class="table scroll table-condensed table-bordered table-striped table-scroll" id="in-app">
   <tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="invoiceApproval in $data">
  
    <td header="'all.html'" class="row-center" style="width:20%"> 
    <input class="myCheckBox" ng-model="invoiceApproval.checkboxItem" type="checkbox" ng-click="checkIfAllSelected()"/></td>
   
    <td data-title="'Customer Name'" style="width:20%" filter="{'customerName':'text'}"  sortable="'customerName'"  class="row-center">
     <div class="row-center">{{invoiceApproval.customerName}}</div>
    </td>
    <td data-title="'Invoice Number'" style="width:20%" sortable="'invoiceNumber'" class="row-center">
     <div class="row-center">{{invoiceApproval.invoiceNumber}}</div>
    </td>
    
    <td data-title="'Invoice Date'" style="width:20%" class="row-center">
     <div class="row-center">{{invoiceApproval.invoiceDate | date}}</div>
    </td>
    
    <!-- <td data-title="'Action'" class="row-center" style="text-align:right">
       <button type="button" class="btn grid-btn row-view sm-btn" ng-click="loadCustomerInvoicePDFviewPDF(invoiceApproval.customerInvoiceHeaderID,1)"> 
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> Preview
       </button>
    </td> -->
   </tr>
   </tbody>
 
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It does work as expected. Unfortunately you didn't show enough code to reproduce your problem. Please compare your solution and ensure your using `ng-include` in the right way:

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table ng-table="invoicetableParams" ng-show="invoicetableParams!=null" class="table scroll table-condensed table-bordered table-striped table-scroll" id="in-app">
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="invoiceApproval in data">
        <td ng-include="'all.html'"></td>
        <td data-title="'Customer Name'" style="width:20%" filter="{'customerName':'text'}" sortable="'customerName'" class="row-center">
          <div class="row-center"> {{invoiceApproval.customerName}}</div>
        </td>
        <td data-title="'Invoice Number'" style="width:20%" sortable="'invoiceNumber'" class="row-center">
          <div class="row-center">{{invoiceApproval.invoiceNumber}}</div>
        </td>
        <td data-title="'Invoice Date'" style="width:20%" class="row-center">
          <div class="row-center">{{invoiceApproval.invoiceDate | date}}</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="all.html">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="invoiceApproval.checkboxItem" ng-click="selectAll()" />
</script>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.selectAll = function() {
    $scope.data.forEach(function(invoiceApproval) {
      return invoiceApproval.checkboxItem = true;
    });
  }

  $scope.invoicetableParams = true;
  $scope.data = [{
      checkboxItem: false,
      customerName: 'test name 1',
      invoiceNumber: 'test name 1',
      invoiceDate: new Date()
    },
    {
      checkboxItem: false,
      customerName: 'test name 2',
      invoiceNumber: 'test name 2',
      invoiceDate: new Date()
    },
    {
      checkboxItem: false,
      customerName: 'test name 3',
      invoiceNumber: 'test name 3',
      invoiceDate: new Date()
    },
    {
      checkboxItem: false,
      customerName: 'test name 4',
      invoiceNumber: 'test name 4',
      invoiceDate: new Date()
    }
  ];
});
```

**> [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pz7wc4bk/)**